# Getting NoMethodError in Active Admin with build_menu command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm customizing a menu in Active Admin. Per the documentation here http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customize_the_menu, I've put this code in the active_admin.rb initialization file:

```
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.build_menu do |menu|
       menu.add :label => "Churches", :url => "/", :priority => 0
       menu.add :label => "Liaisons", :url => "/", :priority => 0

       menu.add :label => "Reports" do |reports|
         reports.add :label => "Google", :url => "http://google.com", :html_options => { :target => :blank }
         reports.add :label => "Facebook", :url => "http://facebook.com"
         reports.add :label => "Github", :url => "http://github.com"
       end
     end
  end
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following error on application initialization: in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method`build_menu' for ActiveAdmin::Namespace:0x007fd241803458> (NoMethodError)

Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what Active Admin version do you have?

Comment: Active Admin version is 0.5.1. I upgraded to this version as part of troubleshooting this error.

Comment: I had the same issue, and it was the active_admin version. Upgrade to 6.0 or more and it fixes it. Thanks @Rick